# Transparent border radius outside

Tags: html, css

I need some help, I have a div with border-radius and I need it to be transparent outside the circle div. I tried with :after and outline. With ":after" the border stayed within the div and with outline I couldn't get it rounded.

Does anyone know the answer ?

CSS :

```
    div.circle {
        background: black;
        width: 5em;
        height: 5em;
        -moz-border-radius: 2.5em;
        -webkit-border-radius: 2.5em;
        border-radius: 2.5em;
    }
   div.circle p {
        padding: 2em 2em 0 2em;
        color: white;
    }
    div.circle:after {
        content:'';
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        border-radius: 2.5em;
        border: 4px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.51);
    }
```

CSS with outline property:

```
   div.circle { 
    outline: 4px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3); 

    background: black; 
    width: 5em; height: 5em; 
    -moz-border-radius: 2.5em; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 2.5em; 
    border-radius: 2.5em;
}
```

What I want: 
http://giovannigras.be/home/img.png

Comment: please provide code you have tried so far

Comment: But put your code here.....Have you tried using `opacity` attribute?

Comment: Can you describe what you want in more detail?
Perhaps a quick js Fiddle to help us understand better

Comment: Dholakiya, you mean a second, bigger circle with opacity? If it's possible, I'd like to do this with only 1 circle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use **box-shadow** instead of *border*:

```
box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.51);
```

Cause a transparent border will transpare the background beneath,
while if you use the `spread` value in the box-shadow property you're good to go:

**[Example demo](http://jsbin.com/suson/2/)**

Also as suggested by @vals you can go with `background-clip` to retain the background size into the `content-box` size model cause otherwise goes into the default *border-box*.

*Docs:*
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip

Answer (score 4):

If you want your border to be transparent (or semitransparent), and you are setting a black background, you need to set the background limited to the inner part, so that the border can be seen.

The property for this is     background-clip: content-box;

CSS

```
div.circle {
    background: black;
    background-clip: content-box;
    width: 5em;
    height: 5em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: solid 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XyM4c/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a container to provide a border offset if you need it.

## [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/parer/1/edit)

#### HTML

```
<div class="border">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.border {
  width: 80px; height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: transparent;  
  border: 10px solid rgba(255,255,255,.4);
}
.inner {
  width: calc(100% - 40px); 
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.6);  
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I wanted it with only 1 div. Thanks though